# Can't create class object from another class

Tags: java, class, object

I'm trying to create a branch Object from Bank class using the addBranch method, but it seems the object is not created since the printOut in the Branch constructor prints something like

"Branch empty created" . Printing a branch list using the corresponding method in Bank class confirms this, as the list is empty.

What's wrong?

//Main

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Bank banco = new Bank("Banco Central");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printOptions();

        boolean quit = false;
        while (!quit) {
            System.out.println("6. Imprimir lista de opciones");
            int option = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
                case 0:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    addBranch();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printBranches();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printOptions();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printOptions() {
        System.out.println("Enter option");
        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        System.out.println("1. Agregar sucursal");
        System.out.println("2. Imprimir sucursales");
        System.out.println("3. Agregar cliente nuevo a sucursal con transaccion inicial");
        System.out.println("4. Agregar transaccion a cliente existente");
        System.out.println("5. Imprimir lista de clientes de sucursal"); //agregar opcional de mostrar transacciones

    }

    public static void addBranch() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la sucursal");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine();

        banco.addBranch(name);
    }

    public static void printBranches() {
        banco.printBranches();

    }


}
```

//Bank class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
    }

    public void addBranch(String branchName) {
        Branch newBranch = new Branch(branchName);
        branches.add(newBranch);
        //System.out.println(nuevaSucursal.getName() + "creada");

    }


    //2

    public void printBranches() {
        System.out.println("Lista de sucursales");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.branches.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.branches.get(i).getName());

        }


    }


    //4
    public void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
        Branch.addTransaction(client, transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo

    }


    //GETTERS & SETTERS

    public ArrayList<Branch> getBranches() { //devolver sout mejor?
        return branches;
    }

    public void addSucursal(String sucursal) {
        this.branches.add(new Branch(sucursal));
    }
}
```

//Branch class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Branch {

    private String branchName;
    ArrayList<Client> clients;

    public Branch(String name) {
        this.branchName = name;
        this.clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }

    public void agregarCliente(String name, double initialTransaction) {
        clients.add(new Client(name, initialTransaction));
        System.out.println("Cliente " + name + " agregado a esta sucursal. Transaccion inicial: " + initialTransaction);
    }

    public static void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
        client.addTransactions(transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo

    }

    public static Branch agregarSucursal(String nombre) {
        return new Branch(nombre);
    }

//GETTERS SETTERS

    public String getName() {
        return this.branchName;
    }
}
```

//Client

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client {

    private String clientName;
    ArrayList<Double> transactions = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public Client(String clientName, double initialTransactions) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.transactions.add(initialTransactions);
        System.out.println("Cliente creado");
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void addTransactions(double transaction) {
        this.transactions.add(transaction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaken -- you're creating the object just fine with this:

```
Branch newBranch= new Branch(branchName);
```

And so object creation is *not* the problem. Rather, the problem is that you're just doing nothing with the object after you have created it -- you must put it into the ArrayList after creation so that it is accessible to the rest of the program:

```
public void addBranch(String branchName) {
   Branch newBranch= new Branch(branchName);
   branches.add(newBranch);
}
```

This is the programming equivalent of buying groceries at the store but forgetting to take them home.  Don't do this and instead remember to take your objects home.

Comment: I understand and added that line.
However the printout after the branch is created still shows empty where it should show it's name.
I'm pretty sure object creation is not a problem, because printing a branch list still prints an empty line for each object created. If i create 2 branches and print a list of branches retreiving the items in the array list it prints 2 empty lines.
What is even more strange is that I changed the argument in the Branch constructor to print the String name argument passed instead of this.branchName, and it also prints an empty space instead of the name passed.

Comment: @1990eam This certainly is a major problem in the code that you posted, but otherwise I can't possibly guess your current problem based on the incomplete picture given. In short, we need a more complete picture of your problem. You need to create and post a valid [mre] if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added the rest of the code so you have the bigger picture. I realized a couple things like the arrayList being initialized twice and corrected it, but the error persists. If you could take a look I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @1990eam it is still missing the main method -- I cannot run the code.

Comment: There, I added it. I just call the class methods from there, so I don't think it's where the bug is. Let me know if you find anything, I'm very curious. And thanks.

Comment: @1990eam: Your *new* problem is in fact within the main method. Please look at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo).  Add a `scanner.nextLine()` after calling `scanner.nextInt()`, not after `scanner.nextLine()`

Comment: Thanks!!! What a stupid bug. I moved the scanner.nextLine before storing the empty line in the name variable and now it works. I knew I had to add that line somewhere to clean the buffer, but it never ocurred to me that was the bug.

Comment: @1990eam: Lesson to learn here: you stated that "I don't think it's where the bug is", when in fact the main method was the source of the bug. Never assume and always *test*